# List-Unsubscribe in Email from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, unsubscribe

We used to have one action in List-Unsubscribe parameter which was mailto but then suddenly Marketing Cloud started to put there a subscription centre which is not set up before mailto. Thus, the subscription logic stopped working. We want to have only mailto there since the logic is related to this action. Or, as an option, we think that if we change places of subscription centre and mailto, we make it possible to unsubscribe from send outs.

Has anyone faced this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The list-unsubscribe header in SFMC marketing emails had historically been limited to only the *mailto:* option, however you are correct, as it recently became possible to utilise the *https:* option as well. This is explained in a.o. [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000332579&type=1).

I acknowledge the poor experience of linking the recipient to the standard Subscription Center page per default. If I were you, I would reach out to support, and raise a case where I would request the *https:* option to be updated, linking the recipient to your correct preference center.

Comment: Lukas, thank you for your answer! I've already reached them. They said that nothing can be done. But I see in the article you've shared that Commercial Messages utilize mailto and then https. Maybe you know how to use them in this order?